# SQL Multiple Groups - It's possible?

Tags: sql

I have a query of this form:

```
SELECT e.date, SUM(e.size) as bytes
FROM entries AS e
GROUP BY e.date
ORDER BY bytes DESC
```

and I have a column named client, which is composed of static values (0,1,2,3), so I want to get this:

```
SELECT e.date, SUM(e.size) as bytes
FROM entries AS e
WHERE e.client = 0
GROUP BY e.date
ORDER BY bytes DESC
```

repeated for every client type but in a single query to get a result of a summarized size for every client type:

```
   DATE    | CLI0-SIZE | CLI1-SIZE | CLI2-SIZE | CLI3-SIZE
2010-11-11      113         344         435         155
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT e.date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.client = 0 THEN e.size ELSE 0 END) as CLI0-SIZE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.client = 1 THEN e.size ELSE 0 END) as CLI1-SIZE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.client = 2 THEN e.size ELSE 0 END) as CLI2-SIZE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.client = 3 THEN e.size ELSE 0 END) as CLI3-SIZE
FROM entries AS e
GROUP BY e.date
```

Answer (score 1):

RDMS: Microsoft SQL Server

This will return the following layout:

```
   date    | client | bytes
2010-11-11 |   2    |  435
2010-11-11 |   1    |  344
2010-11-11 |   3    |  155
2010-11-11 |   0    |  113
```

This will group by all Client types, not just 0,1,2,3 - I assume you wanted this.

```
SELECT
    e.date,
    e.client,
    SUM(e.size) AS bytes
FROM
    entries AS e
GROUP BY
    e.date,
    e.client
ORDER BY
    bytes DESC
```

You can then perform a pivot on the table.

Comment: Not what I was looking for but at least it gets me the info in one query.